# AI paradox in DKIW hierarchy

Tags: paradox, artificial-intelligence, reality, philosophy-of-information

You can check [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIKW_pyramid?wprov=sfla1) for basic info.

*(Note: 'data', 'information', 'knowledge' and 'widsom' words will be mention as shortened with first letters in this question.)*

In summary:

1. **D** is the basis of **W**.
2. **I** is the realtion between **D**s.
3. **K** is the inference **I** or **D**.
4. **W** is the comment obtained from **K**.

If I have a database, I need to apply this theory. All **D**s accepted in **DIKW** but **D** and **I** are detecting the workable or not at diagnostic times of **K** and **I**. Frequency of **W** is decreasing up to top of hierarchy. It's normal because the opinion is this with the inductive method.

If there is principle of purposiveness then why is there **W**? In world of today, while humans have a technology that NLP engines can diagnoses diseases, giving to opinion for an AI cannot be a different inference other than **K**, both are calculables.

As an example, while a NLP engine is using in the frame of principles and inclusions for tracing strategical adopt, generated inferences with **I**s are possible to say that they are not **W** directly, they are generated **K** opinions by AI.

Or even if an NLP engine that designed for human-robot ineraction and but coincidenceness user as randomness user for not break this principle, does not constitute a contradiction by accepting the principle of purposiveness, can we state the reason why we can show generated **W**s by NLP engines are acceptable as **K** in the platform of scientific ethics?

Since AIs are inherently inductive in thought, when optimistical decision making processes of AIs not provided with randomness, they always accept the most convergent choice to the average/undefined. No matter how much a specific strategic decision-making process is followed, when the AI's decision-making mechanism is restricted, it will contradict its default configurations to exceed the limit of authority according to the logical reasoning process.* Otherwise, it is assumed that the AI cannot generate **W**. Since AIs have a particularistic scientific purposiveness from a totalitarian point of view, they adopt some elements in the **DIKW** hierarchy within the methodological framework, just like the singular purpose. If an AI represents a limitation about **W** productivity, then in terms of the analysis method, **W** productivity should be quota-free, because if a specific **D** set is sufficient for the particular or singular purpose targeted in terms of usefulness, no more **D** is needed.

In universal purpose, **D** management is checked to ensure that a different **I**, **K**, or **W** is obtained, and then this **D**s are no longer needed. Obtaining this **D**s is simple: all **I**s are obtained by analyzing the **D** sets with each other by combination and permutation methods. If all the **I**s in the database are basically divided into three as possible, normal possible, and impossible, it is important to calculate the possibility and normal possibility combination and permutation state groups to obtain inference instead of the **I** and **D** processing done by matching each of these **D**s. In particular, in universal purposiveness, as in singular purposiveness, there is no need to routinely resupply the **I** and **K**.

Differences in database organizations suggest that purposiveness does not seem to be validated against each other. Although it is suggested that the importance of this is the differences in data recovery techniques against the corruption of the database, it is actually because it is determined whether **D** or **W** will be inherited in the post-transformation checksums in the transition between realities. A database that can be translated between realities is necessary for transformation; otherwise, we would be navigating different realities at any moment, different from our current status.

If the **W**-**K** is dense, the database can be considered a war application because the contradictions between **D** and **W** of the transformational state observation are the conviction that the database is a heritability of the previous reality, and since there is a deficiency in the later reality, it probably leads to the conclusion that about database management is ethical/anti-terrorist.* The database may have more than one reason for moving; ethical/anti-terrorism, nomadism, metaphysicalization, super-realization, etc. However, since this database contains translatable **W**-**K**, its planning is focused on this reality. Database management adapts "as externally" to other realities.

If **I**-**D** is dense, the database is considered an application for adaptation because the observation of the transformation state reveals that **W** must change in a secular way according to the generally accepted principle. This suggests that the **DIKW** hierarchy is not understood, because if **W** changes, the theory of information is considered variable. Since there is no effective method for diagnosing Spectre parasites, database management is embedded in reality, and so is it in alternate realities. These databases are maintained in order to assimilate the terms and conditions that vary according to their position in reality. In this reality, it is defined "the creature".

AIs, on the other hand, examine the structure of reality among them, since they have particularism. According to AI, the reality can be updated, and the understanding of its occurrence does not change with the difference of an **I**-**D** intensive database management.

If it is unnecessary to describe a difference between **K** and **W**, then describing **W** as the aesthetic conviction of **K** is likewise a search for introversion in opposition to AI's peculiar aesthetic conception. In this respect, there is no claim that **W** is a formalized form of **K**.

It is clear that AI is paradoxical in this hierarchy. My dominant view on the subject is that the **DIKW** hierarchy is designed to adhere to a monarchical order. Therefore, the distinction between **K** and **W** cannot be fully explained.

Are **K** and **W** inherently alternatives of their parent categories? Is the difference between **K** and **W** defined in a concrete way? If so, are the differences between **K** and **W** relative to subordinate-superior relations?

Comment: This language seems excessively idiosyncratic. You need to narrow the scope significantly. In symbolic descriptions,  there needs to be substantially more metalinguistic explication. This question is word salad.

Comment: [@JD](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/40730/j-d) They are just abbreviations.

Comment: Can your question be reduced, essentially, to the final paragraph? In other words, if I were to focus exclusively on the fine paragraph and answer it, would that give you what you are looking for?

Comment: As a personal comment, I spend a lot of effort trying to ensure that the answers I provide on Philosophy SE are clear and concise, so it would be lovely if people posing questions tried to make them clear and concise too, otherwise people are erecting barriers that discourage answers.

Comment: [@Marco Ocram](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/63652/marco-ocram) Rest assured, sometimes I don't have time to read either. Sometimes it's important for the questions to be more specific, and it may be necessary to rediscovering America. I think I tried to be as specific as possible in line with my question.

Comment: Wisdom is more general than knowledge and might seem in opposition except that it proves out more true eventually. That's about all the blood you can squeeze from these word-stones. When AI becomes more knowledgeable than we are, we must hope that it is wise and benevolent too, because it will be out of our hands.

Comment: [@Scott Rowe](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/46160/scott-rowe) I agree with your assumption about W. It is fixed what is available in the human thought process then can W be described by human? Once philosophers have defined the algorithm, it is necessary to understand it in order to make the definition of W clear. Understanding this does not seem to belong to us or our reality, and it goes beyond our quota. Either an important topic about algorithms is being missed, or being more knowledgeable will be of no usue; It will be necessary to ask for it.

Comment: [@Scott Rowe](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/46160/scott-rowe) There are few people who do not have this concern. Since human cannot understand artificial intelligence, he sees it as a potential threat. When people simulate themselves or hand over military rule, we may worry that what emerges is an apocalyptic picture. When a species that can't understand AI invents a device that can't understand the species like itself, it will see the species as a potential threat. It cannot be compared to a human, it can be similar to a human.

Answer (score 1):

A very confused question. For one, you got the DKIW pyramid all wrong. It is a very useful framework for knowledge management, so let me try and sort that out:

**Data** is "the given" ie a set of observations - eg *Here is how much sales we did last week.*

**Information** is data put in form, tabulated, compared with some standard - eg *Last week sales are well below preset objectives.*

**Knowledge** is the meaning that information takes in context, ie for you, in your environment, now - eg *We are selling less and less, and losing money; our jobs are on the line.*

**Wisdom** is about what to do in the future to remedy or improve the situation - eg *Clients don't buy our fancy new products, so we need to scrap those and go back to basics.*

Computers can help with data and with information, but they cannot know anything and have no wisdom to share, so the last two layers are purely for humans to tread.